# How to pass a func<> in linq to sql with a join

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have the following issue.

I want to pass a func as parameter so it can vary in the where statement.

```
   private IEnumerable<User> GetUser(int cant, Func<User, bool> userFilter, Func<Client, bool> ClientFilter)
    {
        return (from dcu in
                    _db.All<User>().Where(userFilter)
                join c in _db.All<Client>() on dcu.IdClient equals c.IdClient into temp
                from cli in temp.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(ClientFilter)
                select new {Usuer = dcu, Client = cli}).
            Take(cant).Select(uc => _usersMapper.Map(uc.User, uc.Client)).AsEnumerable();

    }
```

And the func should look like this

```
    public void GetUsers ()
    {
        GetUser(50, u => u.Email.Contains("onemail@mail.com"), c=> true);
    }
    public void GetUsersFilterByClient ()
    {
        GetUser(50, u => true, c=> c.Password.Contains("MyPasssword"));
    }
```

Comment: have you tried `Expression<Func<User, bool>>` as the param?

Comment: `Where` is expecting a method that takes 1 param and return true. `GetUsers` doesn't satisfy that requirement in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to lambda your `Where` into the `filter` function:

```
private IEnumerable<User> GetUser(int cant, Func<User, bool> filter)
{
    return (from dcu in _db.All<User>().Where(a => filter(a))
            join c in _db.All<Client>() on dcu.IdClient equals c.IdClient into temp
            from cli in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new {Usuer = dcu, Client = cli}).
        Take(cant).Select(uc => _usersMapper.Map(uc.User, uc.Client)).AsEnumerable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from a repository implementation I created - the Func approach should suffice:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ContentType> FindImpl(Func<ContentType, bool> matchPredicate)
{
    return _context.ContentTypes.Where(matchPredicate);
}
```